# Ignore thumbnail space if there is no thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have the below code that loops through my posts and displays posts in a list format. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="one-sixth first"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
    <div class="five-sixths"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Here is the image with the thumbnail:
[image]

Here is when no post thumbnail is available, it just leaves an empty space:
[image]

Comment: can you set width for '.one-sixth{width:200px}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If check thumbnail if have displayed otherwise display placeholder image. Hope this help you.

```
<?php
// Must be inside a loop.

if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
}
else {
    echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) 
        . '/images/placeholder.jpg" />';
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks man! Is the /images/ directory a post_attachment directory?

Comment: No your theme folder inside images/

Comment: Works like a charm - Accepted answer.